# Query for total number of people reporting to manager in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a usual question asked in interviews.
Please get the managers information i.e. manager's id, his name and total number of employees reporting to him.

There is a single table

```
GS_Employee
```

Its as follows,

```
-- Creation of Employeee table
create table GS_EMPLOYEE(
    emp_id number(3) primary key,
    emp_name varchar2(100),
    division_id number (3) references GS_DIVISION,
    manager_id number(3) references GS_EMPLOYEE 
)
```

Please ignore the 'GS_Division' table mapping. From the above table you will see that the employee table holds information of manager's also, because, manager also is an employee. So column 'manager_id' is referencing to the same table

```
manager_id number(3) references GS_EMPLOYEE
```

If I write a plain SQL query, a self join gives me a desired result as follows,

```
select      em.emp_id,
            em.emp_name, 
            mgr.TOTAL_JUNIORS
from        GS_EMPLOYEE em,
            (select e2.emp_id as EMPLOYEE_ID,
                    count(e1.emp_id) as TOTAL_JUNIORS 
                from GS_EMPLOYEE e1, 
                    GS_EMPLOYEE e2 
                where e1.manager_Id = e2.emp_id 
                group by (e2.emp_id)
            ) mgr
where       em.emp_id = mgr.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

But, I need to use Hibernate to Solve the above problem

Hence I created an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GS_EMPLOYEE")
@NamedQuery(name="getAllEmployeesQuery",query ="from Employee e order by e.employeeId asc")    
public class Employee  implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1035435388896L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    private Integer employeeId;

    @Column(name="EMP_NAME")
    private String employeeName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Division.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="DIVISION_ID")
    private Division division;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Employee.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="MANAGER_ID")
    private Employee manager;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Employee.class,mappedBy="manager",cascade= {CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=false)
    private Set<Employee> employeeList;
```

In my EmployeeDAOImpl.java class I have written the method

```
public List<Employee> getManagerAndJuniors() throws Exception{
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Employee> q =  session.getNamedQuery("getAllEmployeesQuery");
        List<Employee> list = q.list();
        return list;
    }
```

The above method fetches all the employees,

Now In the service layer i.e. EmployeeServiceImpl.java I do the filtering,

```
public List<Employee> getManagerAndJuniors() throws Exception{
        List<Employee> managerList = this.dao.getManagerAndJuniors();
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        managerList.forEach((Employee mgr) -> {
            Set<Employee> empList = null;   
            try {
                empList = mgr.getEmployeeList();

                if(empList != null && empList.size() > 0) {
                    list.add(mgr);
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        });

        return list;
    }
```

Now now I am able to filter all the managers, which I add into a new List, and return.

Can I do some JPQL or Hibernate Query to solve the same problem as I did in my plain SQL query.

I am using Oracle as database.

Answer (score 0):

Hql does not support subquery in a `from` clause. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-subqueries

Note the sentence :

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

Why don't you just use this query without subquery :

```
select manager.emp_id, manager.emp_name, count(*) as TOTAL_JUNIORS
from GS_EMPLOYEE manager
inner join GS_EMPLOYEE employee on manager.emp_id = employee.manager_id 
where manager.manager_id = manager.emp_id
group by emp_id, emp_name;
```